# Responsive Images Gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hopefully this will be a no brainer for someone. Essentially what I am trying to acheive is as follows.

Depending on the viewport width will depend on the amount of images shown, these images will always fill the space 100% but less images will be shown depending on the width.

HTML may be:

```
<div class="image">
            <img src="XXXX.jpg"/> 
</div>
<div class="image">
            <img src="XXXX.jpg"/> 
</div>
<div class="image">
            <img src="XXXX.jpg"/> 
</div>
<div class="image">
            <img src="XXXX.jpg"/> 
</div>
<div class="image">
            <img src="XXXX.jpg"/> 
</div>
<div class="image">
            <img src="XXXX.jpg"/> 
</div>
<div class="image">
            <img src="XXXX.jpg"/> 
</div>
```

So on a screen over 1200px we would display all images (on a single row) whereas on a screen of say 400px or less we would display only 2 images.

I guess there is a JS solution out there but I am relatively new to JS and cannot seem to find a solution that is understandable and relatable.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What would be shown on a screen of width > 400 and < 1200?

Comment: It would be best to do this with CSS media queries. Rather than JavaScript. Media queries tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: will the resolution of images consistent? what will happen if couple of images with 200 X 300 and other with 100 X 400?

Comment: it will be better to use combination of media query and JavaScript. See this http://miromannino.github.io/Justified-Gallery/

Comment: Thank you for the responses. Using media queries make perfect sense, the complication (possibly) is that I would want to hide any excess images so there is always only a single row.

For example I have the six images in the code, but on mobile I would only display the first 2 images at a width of 50% each, the other 4 would be hidden.

Answer (score 1):

There's a CSS solution. You can use media queries to do that.

```
@media (max-width: 400px){
    //your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No media Queries required

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">    
<div class="image">
                <img src="XXXX.jpg"/> 
    </div>
    <div class="image">
                <img src="XXXX.jpg"/> 
    </div>
    <div class="image">
                <img src="XXXX.jpg"/> 
    </div>
    <div class="image">
                <img src="XXXX.jpg"/> 
    </div>
    <div class="image">
                <img src="XXXX.jpg"/> 
    </div>
    <div class="image">
                <img src="XXXX.jpg"/> 
    </div>
    <div class="image">
                <img src="XXXX.jpg"/> 
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper{width:100%;overflow:hidden}
.wrapper .image{float:left;}
```

Comment: This can be handled by using 'Max-height' property since all the images will be of same height. [https://jsfiddle.net/g1mhor3c/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/g1mhor3c/1/)

Comment: agree, but what will happen if you don't know the height of largest image in the collection; say all the images are loading dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

**it is tested:**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="image f_left">
        <img src="bill.png"/> 
</div>
<div class="image f_left">
        <img src="bill.png"/> 
</div>
<div class="image f_left">
        <img src="bill.png"/> 
</div>
<div class="image f_left">
        <img src="bill.png"/> 
</div>
<div class="image f_left">
        <img src="bill.png"/> 
</div>
<div class="image f_left">
        <img src="bill.png"/> 
</div>
<div class="image f_left">
        <img src="bill.png"/> 
</div>
```

**CSS:** must be

```
.f_left
{
    float:left;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
     /* Smartphone view: 1 tile */
   .image{
       width: 100%;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 650px) and (min-width : 481px) {
     /* Tablet view: 2 tiles */
   .image {
       width: 50%;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 1050px) and (min-width : 651px) {
    /* Small desktop / ipad view: 3 tiles */
    .image {
        width: 33.3%;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 1290px) and (min-width : 1051px) {
     /* Medium desktop: 4 tiles */
     .image {
        width: 25%;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 1600px) and (min-width : 1291px) {
     /* Medium desktop: 4 tiles */
     .image {
        width: 20%;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the responses. Using media queries make perfect sense, the complication (possibly) is that I would want to hide any excess images so there is always only a single row.

For example I have the six images in the code, but on mobile I would only display the first 2 images at a width of 50% each, the other 4 would be hidden.